# Why are variables inside a struct not being assigned any value?

Tags: c, variables, struct

In the debugger, I see that the pointer has the right address that I want and the variables
`UBRR_VAL`, `val1`, `val2` hold the passed in values. Only problem is that the variables inside the struct `_UBRRH`, `_UBRRL`, `_UCSRA` and `_UCSRB` are not changing.  Below you will find code snippets for reference.  Thanks.

This is how the `struct` is defined

```
typedef uint8_t volatile DEVICEREGISTER;

typedef struct
{
    DEVICEREGISTER _UDR;
    DEVICEREGISTER _UCSRA;
    DEVICEREGISTER _UCSRB;
    DEVICEREGISTER _UBRRL;
} uart_register_t;

#define _USART (uart_register_t*) 0x2C
```

This is how I am calling the function.

```
uart_init(UBRR_VAL, 0, (1<<_TXC)|(1<<_RXC), _USART); // initialize the uart for outputting and inputting.
```

Below is the function definition.

```
void uart_init(uint8_t UBRR_VAL, uint8_t val1, uint8_t val2, uart_register_t *pointer)
{
    pointer->_UBRRL = UBRR_VAL;                     
    pointer->_UCSRA = val1; 
    pointer->_UCSRB = val2;
}
```

Comment: You should qualify your parameter named `pointer` to a pointer to a `volatile` object in the function prototype.

Comment: Identifiers starting with an underscore and an uppercase letter are reserved to the implementation; you shouldn't use then in your own code.

Comment: Your question mentions `_UBRRH` but nothing in the structure corresponds to it.  How do you know that the values are not set?  Can you read from the UART addresses that you write to?  Does it take time for the UART to react to you writing to the various memory locations?

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it. You're allowed to do that and it makes the question appear answered and solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate everybody's feedback on this question. It helped me narrow down the issue and finally resolved it. It turns out I had the variables inside the struct in the wrong sequential order. I fixed that problem now. Thank you very much for helping me resolve this issue!